# What "SITE URL" a FB app should have for a hybrid mobile app?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, hybrid-mobile-app

I have an application that needs to be exported for iPhone and Android. This app has a option: **Connect with Facebook**.

So, I've created a FB app and in the settings is an input that requests the SITE URL. Since my app is a hybrid app, I don't have any site url. I've tried with http://localhost, but it dones't work.

My guess is that I need to make the login with a backend services, but I don't know how, or what is the API for javascript to connect with...Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use site URL only if you have a web App. If your App is only iPhone and Android you have to remove "Website" platform from your App settings and add iPhone and Android platform